# How to SQL query parent-child for specific JSON format?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

I am expecting this JSON for my jQuery code:

```
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "project_name": "Carmichael House",
      "parent_id": "0",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "2",
          "project_name": "Carmichael Kitchen",
          "parent_id": "1"
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "project_name": "Carmichael Bathroom",
          "parent_id": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "project_name": "Dowd Apartment",
      "parent_id": "0",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "4",
          "project_name": "Dowd Kitchen",
          "parent_id": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This data will come from MySql table **`tbl_projects`**:

```
id
project_name
parent_id
```

What should the SQL `SELECT` query be, so that it will output **1 flat table**, that can easily be converted into JSON (in PHP or JavaScript/jQuery)?

Am I even approaching this the right way?

Comment: Which version of MySQL? It matters because only later versions support recursive Common Table Expressions.

Comment: MySql version 5.7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can generate JSON content directly from MySQL. Here is a solution that works with MySQL 5.7 or higher.

As a starter, coonsider [function `JSON_OBJECT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object), that generates a JSON object for each record in the table:

```
SELECT 
    p.*, 
    JSON_OBJECT('id', id, 'project_name', project_name, 'parent_id', parent_id) js
FROM tbl_projects p;
```

Given your sample data, this returns:

```
| id  | project_name        | parent_id | js                                                               |
| --- | ------------------- | --------- | ---------------------------------------------------------------- |
| 1   | Carmichael House    | 0         | {"id": 1, "parent_id": 0, "project_name": "Carmichael House"}    |
| 2   | Carmichael Kitchen  | 1         | {"id": 2, "parent_id": 1, "project_name": "Carmichael Kitchen"}  |
| 3   | Carmichael Bathroom | 1         | {"id": 3, "parent_id": 1, "project_name": "Carmichael Bathroom"} |
| 4   | Dowd Apartment      | 0         | {"id": 4, "parent_id": 0, "project_name": "Dowd Apartment"}      |
| 5   | Dowd Kitchen        | 4         | {"id": 5, "parent_id": 4, "project_name": "Dowd Kitchen"}        |
```

To generate your expected output, we will self-`JOIN` the table to find children records, and use [aggregate function `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) to generate the inner JSON array. An additional level of aggregation stuffs everything into a single object. As showned in your sample data, I assumed that root projects have `parent_id = 0` and that there is only one level of hierarchy:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('projects', JSON_ARRAYAGG(js)) results
FROM (
    SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
        'id', p.id, 
        'project_name', p.project_name, 
        'parent_id', p.parent_id,
        'children', JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_OBJECT(
                'id', p1.id, 
                'project_name', p1.project_name, 
                'parent_id', p1.parent_id
            )
        )
    ) js
    FROM tbl_projects p
    LEFT JOIN tbl_projects p1 ON p.id = p1.parent_id
    WHERE p.parent_id = 0
    GROUP BY p.id, p.project_name, p.parent_id
) x
```

Yields:

```
| results                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| {"projects": [{"id": 1, "children": [{"id": 2, "parent_id": 1, "project_name": "Carmichael Kitchen"}, {"id": 3, "parent_id": 1, "project_name": "Carmichael Bathroom"}], "parent_id": 0, "project_name": "Carmichael House"}, {"id": 4, "children": [{"id": 5, "parent_id": 4, "project_name": "Dowd Kitchen"}], "parent_id": 0, "project_name": "Dowd Apartment"}]} |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mr81oyYKLHCdoRB88TErS3/0)**

Comment: WOW. You are equally fantastic as JSON_OBJECT() is.

Comment: Welcome Rollor... Such feedback sounds fantastic to my ears!