# json object becoming string because double quotes are added?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I have data coming from MySql, answered from this:
[How to SQL query parent-child for specific JSON format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55211880/how-to-sql-query-parent-child-for-specific-json-format/55212162?noredirect=1#comment97160936_55212162). Basically I query it using `JSON_OBJECT()` which produces the result:

`results`  `<-- The column name`

```
{"projects": "project_name": "project 1", [2nd layer stuff]}  <-- the row
```

Awesome. MySql did the json thing for me. I make an ajax call to a `PHP` function to get this onto the web server.:

```
myPhpFunction () {
    //some usual PDO code
    echo json_encode($query_result);
}
```

On JS, I make a jQuery ajax call:

```
var ajaxRequest =
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '../includes/ajax.php',
        data: 'action' : 'myPhpFunction',
        dataType: 'json'
      });

      ajaxRequest.done(function(data) { 
        //$.each(data[0].results.projects, function(key, val){ 
            //I want to access each stuff in the object here
        //}
        $('#ph-projects').append(JSON.stringify(data)); //testing it out
      }
```

The problem I'm having is by this time, my object `data` outputs like this:

```
{ "results": "{...}" }
```

**results value is a string because of those double quotes!**

This is driving me crazy. Am I missing a step to prevent this from happening?

Comment: If your MYSQL is already returning a json string, why are you encoding it again?

Comment: If I don't do json_encode() in php, my JS says it gets an Array

Comment: Could you try `JSON.parse(data)` instead of stringify?

Comment: You need to show how you fetch the rows and encode them.  That's where the problem is.

Comment: @Rollor can you please do a `die(gettype($query_result));`  before the `return json_encode($query_result);` and post the results? and if its an array, do `die(gettype($query_result['results']));`

Comment: @AakashMore it says "array"

Comment: @Rollor Please also do `die(gettype($query_result['results']));`

Comment: @AakashMore, I did an `echo var_dump($query_result)`, it gives `array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["results"]=> string(291)...`

Comment: @Rollor, I got your problem and posted the answer. A side note, `var_dump();` doesn't need an `echo`.  Accept & upvote the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `json_encode()` is working fine as it is providing the result as a JSON object as suggested by your question(`{ "results": "{...}" }`). And `JSON_OBJECT()` in PDO returning a string is fine as the name *JSON* suggests, its *JavaScript Object Notation* in a humanly readable format.

You can do on the server side:

`json_encode(['results'=> json_decode($query_result['results'])]);`

**or** on client side,

```
function(data){ 
    data.results = JSON.parse(data.results);
    // Your json data here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I only tried the client-side version first: `var jdata = JSON.parse(data[0].results);`, then worked on `jdata`